# Moderated Mediation

Tags: interaction, spss, mediation

Does anyone know the process model # for a moderated mediation, where the independent variable (in this diagram A) moderates the effect of the mediator (B) on C? I attached a diagram below. Alternatively, if anyone happens to know of any papers that use this model that would also be super helpful. I am seeing a lot of models/papers, where there's an external moderator that moderates the effect of the mediator on the dependent variable. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]